# Behavior of relative URIs in XML when declaration source is parameter entity replacement text

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, specifications, dtd

I’m trying to understand the correct behavior of relative system ID URIs. First, let me quote the spec:

> 4.2.2 External Entities
>
> [...]
>
> [The location of the resource within which the entity declaration occurs] is defined to be the external entity containing the '<' which starts the declaration, at the point when it is parsed as a declaration.
>
> A URI might thus be relative to the document entity, to the entity containing the external DTD subset, or to some other external parameter entity. [...]

On first reading, I thought these two statements were contradictory. It seemed to me that the parsing of any text *“as a declaration”* may only occur in two contexts: an internal subset or an external subset. This seems to follow naturally from the fact that entity dereferencing/expansion is recursive. So how can "some other external parameter entity" ever be what an ID is relative to?

For both statements to be true, perhaps the phrase "point when it is parsed" just doesn’t mean what I took it to mean. Could the "point" here refer instead to whatever context defined the source text?

I’m going to provide an example that might help make this question more imminently answerable.

First, our document. This could be anywhere, since the external DTD it references uses an absolute URL for a system ID.

```
FILE: doc.xml

    <!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd">
    ...
```

So next up is the DTD — unambiguously to be found at `http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd`:

```
FILE: http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd

    <!ENTITY % bar SYSTEM "bar/bar.ent">
    %bar;
```

Still nothing ambiguous. It’s clear that our next resource is to be found at `http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent`

```
FILE: http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent

    <!ENTITY % baz SYSTEM "baz/baz.ent">
    %baz;
```

But here’s where I get unsure. Given that the spec specifically states that it is possible for a path to be relative to an external parameter entity, the only thing I can think of is that here, the absolute path for the `baz` entity must be `http://dotcom.xml/bar/baz/baz.ent`.

This seemed odd to me because the content of an external parameter entity is, beyond the text declaration, just a blob of text whose context and meaning is unknowable until later, when (and if) it is referenced in either an internal or external subset. But it’s not crazy — keeping track of the origin in simple enough.

But why, then, does the spec qualify their statement with "at the point when it is parsed"? Well, it could be that *this* is different:

```
FILE: http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd

    <!ENTITY % bar SYSTEM "bar/bar.ent">
    %bar;
    %baz;

FILE: http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent

    <!ENTITY % baz SYSTEM "baz/baz.ent">
```

But that doesn’t seem to work. I’m pretty sure it doesn’t make sense to say that the relative context is different now, because the entity declaration’s `<` still "happened" in `bar.ent`. The spec specifically calls that point out. In fact, if the location of the reference mattered, then it would seem to have to always be `http://dotcom.xml/baz/baz.ent`, since the actual expansion takes place "back at home" in `foo.dtd` no matter how many intermediate parameter entities there are between it and `baz`.

So I’m looking to understand two things:

1. Above, what is the correct absolute URL for `"baz/baz.ent"`?
2. a. If it is `http://dotcom.xml/bar/baz/baz.ent`, why does the spec says "at the point where it is parsed"?

   b. If it is `http://dotcom.xml/baz/baz.ent`, why does the spec say "or to some other external parameter entity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question(s).

Unlike my esteemed co-editor, I don't think this is a corner case at
all; lots of public DTDs instantiate this pattern.  But I do think
that in the normal cases like this one, most XML parsers get the right
answer.

First, some general points.

1 The general principle for resolution of relative references against
a base URI is, roughly, that normally the base URI that counts is the
base URI of the resource within which the relative reference is used.

2 It's the job of the XML spec to say what it means for a relative
resource found in an entity declaration to be "used" in the relevant
sense, and where to look for the appropriate base URI.  The spec's
answer is given in the passage you cite.  It amounts to saying that
the relative reference is *used* when the parameter entity declaration
containing it is parsed as a parameter entity declaration, and not at
some other time, and that base URI to use is the base URI of the
entity within which the PE declaration occurs.

3 Since as you observe PE references are expanded recursively, the
collection of PE references being expanded at any given point in the
parse is modeled by a stack.  The base URI for any given relative
reference is the URI of the external entity at the top of the stack
when the declaration containing that relative reference is parsed.

I will pass in silence over the details of what kinds of entity
reference are handled at what time, and the motivation for the
details; the short unmotivated answer is that when PE references are
found in the replacement text of a declaration, they are to be
expanded immediately; when general entity references are encountered
(as they may be in the replacement text of another entity), they are
not to be expanded; they are to be expanded when encountered in
parsing the document instance, but not when parsing the DTD.

> First, our document. This could be anywhere, since the external
>   DTD it references uses an absolute URL for a system ID.
>
> FILE: doc.xml

When we start processing this file, an entry of the form

- `#document` "file://Users/semicolon/docs/doc.xml"

is pushed onto the entity stack, and the relevant base URI for any
resolutions is "file://Users/semicolon/docs/doc.xml".

One consequence of the well-formedness rules of XML is that when we
finish reading that entity and the stack becomes empty, the XML
document is over.

```
    <!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd">
    ...
```

> So next up is the DTD — unambiguously to be found at
>   http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd:
>
> FILE: http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd

Once we start parsing this external subset, the entity stack will look
something like this:

- `#dtd-external` "http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd"
- `#document` "file://Users/semicolon/docs/doc.xml"

and the base URI to be used in relative reference resolution is
"http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd".

N.B. Both of the entities now on the stack are strictly speaking
anonymous; for convenience I have given them names beginning '#' (to
avoid possible conflicts with named entities), but that's just for
convenience, because it's easier to refer to '#dtd-external' in an
error message than "That resource you pointed to from the SYSTEM
identifier in your document type declaration."

```
    <!ENTITY % bar SYSTEM "bar/bar.ent">
    %bar;
```

> Still nothing ambiguous. It’s clear that our next resource is to
>   be found at http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent

Well, depending on what you mean by "next", that's either true or
false.  If you mean "after we process http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd, we
then process http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent," then it's false.  The
file .../bar.ent is processed *during* the processing of .../foo.dtd,
not after.  If you mean "the next entity to be pushed onto the entity
stack is the PE 'bar'", then it's true.

If the two lines you've shown are the beginning of file "foo.dtd", and
are followed by further declarations, the PE 'bar' must be parsed and
processed *before* those following declarations.  Even if nothing
follows the PE reference %bar; but whitespace or EOF, strictly
speaking the external parameter entity 'bar' should be processed
immediately when the reference to it is recognized, and thus before
the following EOF is encountered.

But I agree that the correct resolution of the relative reference is 
the absolute reference you specify.

> FILE: http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent

Once we start reading this entity, the entity stack is:

- `bar` "http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent"
- `#dtd-external` "http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd"
- `#document` "file://Users/semicolon/docs/doc.xml"

and the base URI for resolutions is `http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent`

```
    <!ENTITY % baz SYSTEM "baz/baz.ent">
    %baz;
```

> But here’s where I get unsure. Given that the spec specifically
>   states that it is possible for a path to be relative to an
>   external parameter entity, the only thing I can think of is that
>   here, the absolute path for the baz entity must be
>   http://dotcom.xml/bar/baz/baz.ent.

Yes.

> This seemed odd to me because the content of an external parameter
>       entity is, beyond the text declaration, just a blob of text whose
>       context and meaning is unknowable until later, when (and if) it is
>       referenced in either an internal or external subset. But it’s not
>       crazy — keeping track of the origin in simple enough.

For parameter-entity references, there is no "later" in the sense you
mean, I think.  (I may of course misunderstand you.)  The reference is
expanded, and parsed, at the point of recognition.  And in any case,
in the example both 'bar' and 'baz' *have* been referenced in the
external subset.  But the rules you quote from the XML spec have the
consequence that the absolute URI for any external parameter entity is
in principle well defined, whether it's referred to or not.

> But why, then, does the spec qualify their statement with "at the
>       point when it is parsed"? Well, it could be that this is
>       different:
>
> FILE: http://dotcom.xml/foo.dtd

```
    <!ENTITY % bar SYSTEM "bar/bar.ent">
    %bar;
    %baz;
```

> FILE: http://dotcom.xml/bar/bar.ent

```
   <!ENTITY % baz SYSTEM "baz/baz.ent">
```

> But that doesn’t seem to work. I’m pretty sure it doesn’t make
>       sense to say that the relative context is different now, because
>       the entity declaration’s < still "happened" in bar.ent. The spec
>       specifically calls that point out.

Agreed (I think).

> In fact, if the location of the
>       reference mattered, then it would seem to have to always be
>       http://dotcom.xml/baz/baz.ent, since the actual expansion takes
>       place "back at home" in foo.dtd no matter how many intermediate
>       parameter entities there are between it and baz.

No, expansion of PE references takes place immediately, 'in' the
entity in which they are encountered.  It doesn't matter for anything
but error messages and absolutization of relative references, perhaps, but it's clear.

The reference to "the point when [the PE declaration] is parsed" is
intended to cover cases like the following.  In one parameter entity A
we have a declaration of the form

```
<!ENTITY % chapdecl '&#x003C;!ENTITY % chapters SYSTEM "chapters.dtd">'>
```

This is not the declaration of a parameter entity 'chapters', but the
declaration of a parameter entity 'chapdecl' containing the
declaration of 'chapters'.

In another parameter entity B, which is encountered and processed
later, we have the parameter entity reference

```
%chapdecl;
```

I read the spec as telling us that the relative reference
"chapters.dtd" is relative to the base URI of B, not of A.

I am relieved to see that I came the same conclusion a few years ago
at http://cmsmcq.com/mib/?p=1289 (although the program I was working
on then does the wrong thing in this corner case).

> So I’m looking to understand two things:
>
> Above, what is the correct absolute URL for "baz/baz.ent"?
>
> a. If it is http://dotcom.xml/bar/baz/baz.ent, why does the spec
>       says "at the point where it is parsed"?

It is.

The spec says what it does in an attempt (apparently not
completely successful) to make clear that the relevant base URI is
that of the entity E that contains the declaration D that contains the
relative reference R to "baz/baz.ent".

The slightly cumbersome wording is also trying to say (I think) that
in unusual (or pathological) cases like the A/B case above, where the
actual string that looks like a PE declaration occurs in one entity
and the parsing rules say that it's recognized and processed as a PE
declaration in another entity, it's the latter entity (B in the
example) whose base URI is used, not the one that contains the string
(A).  A contains a string which *looks* like a declaration; B contains
(via the expansion of 'chapdecl') the *declaration*.  (Strictly
speaking, the top entity on the entity stack when the declaration is
encountered is 'chapdecl', but it's not an external entity so it
doesn't count.)

In case it helps, the antecedent of 'it' in the sentence is
'declaration', and we are talking about the point at which the
declaration is parsed, not the point at which the entity's replacement
text is parsed.

> b. If it is http://dotcom.xml/baz/baz.ent, why does the spec say
>       "or to some other external parameter entity"?

It's not, and the spec says "or to some other external parameter
entity" in part to make clear that it's not.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This cleared up not only my specific question, but also helped clarify my understanding of the terminology used the spec in many other places. e.g. while I understood the reasoning behind "all external parameter entities are well-formed by definition", I was still baffled as to why there was no explicit production, e.g. `textDecl? char*` — now I see that throughout the spec PEs are treated as if they are read and parsed at usage time. [...]

Comment: [...] That *is* true, but in practice, I’ve been reading the textDecl & caching the (as yet unparsed) remainder upon first use for efficiency, and I wasn’t properly separating this out-of-band implementation detail from my reading of the spec, hence my discussing blobs of text etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ouf, that is a corner case.  I think we can agree that it shouldn't matter where you refer to %baz; from.  I'm pretty sure the intent is that "relative" should mean "relative to the file in which the declaration appears".  Since we rarely as in never hear complaints about interoperation between one XML processor and another (Yay), I bet they all do the same thing, and I hope that's what it is.  But I haven't tested.